# fourier series analysis, show that for every integer n, using euler's formulas relating trigonometric and exponential functions

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, proof-writing, fourier-series

Show that for every integer $n$,

$$\int_0^{\pi} \cos nt~\sin t~\mathrm{d}t = \begin{cases} \dfrac{2}{1-n^2} & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\[10pt]
0 &\text{if } n \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

by using Euler's formulas relating trigonometric and exponential functions:

$$\cos x=\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{ix}+\mathrm{e}^{-ix}), \ \ \ 
\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}(\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix})$$

(Here $i$ is the imaginary unit; remember that $\mathrm{e}^{\pi i} = -1$)

I am not sure how to go about doing this problem, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated, thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It is a straightforward calculations! Just change the integrand in terms of the exponential function and do the resulted integral

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they: Briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim. Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea). Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand this integral you should get:
$$\int_0^\pi \cos(nt)\sin(t)dt = \frac{1}{4i}\int_0^\pi \left(e^{int}+e^{-int}\right)\left(e^{it}-e^{-it}\right)dt$$
$$= \frac{1}{4i}\int_0^\pi e^{i(n+1)t} - e^{i(n-1)t} + e^{-i(n-1)t} - e^{-i(n+1)t}dt$$

Note that this is exactly the sum of sines:
$$= i\int_0^\pi \sin((n+1)t)-\sin((n-1)t)dt$$
Now perform the integration and note that $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider if the function is even or odd for $n$ even or odd (with respect to the mid point $\pi /2$), this will get your odd case dealt with. To deal with the even case, use the double angle formula repeatedly.